# Using Imagemagick to replicate photoshop's "expand selection" functionality

Tags: php, image, imagemagick, edge-detection

I'm looking to use Imagemagick (via PHP) to process PNGs with transparent backgrounds and some semi-transparent pixels (like gradients). The images will have to be altered like so:
1. make all non-transparent pixels the same, solid color (black is fine)
2. expand the edges of the shapes within the image by a 25 pixels

With this input (transparent BG, some pixels are semi-transparent):
[image: Input PNG]

I expect output like this:
[image: Output PNG]

This isn't just resizing the image. I'm looking for functionality similar to how photoshop expands a selection (for example, the gap in the top circle is negated because it's smaller than the 25 pixel expansion).

Currently, I have code that scans an image and finds the edges, but fails when there are multiple shapes that aren't connected within an image. Does Imagemagick have a way to do this or is there an algorithm I can use to scan an image and generate the output I need? Speed *is* a concern, but I can live with a slow solution as long as it works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This answer is a work in progress, I think we can get you there though...

Basically, your step 1) means you want to set the RGB channels to black across the entire image, whilst leaving the transparency to determine the shapes - I think. Well, we can do that lots of ways, but let's use a threshold like this:

```
convert shapes.png -threshold 100% result.png
```

[image]

Now you want to expand the selection, but the selection is only really in the Alpha/transparency channel so we restrict our operations to that channel which will keep the speed up.  In morphological terms, you are looking for a dilation, so you can do something like this:

```
convert shapes.png -threshold 100% -channel A -morphology dilate octagon:25 result.png
```

There are other shapes (disk, diamond, etc) and other degrees of dilation (I chose 25 dilations) - have a look at Anthony Thyssen's excellent ImageMagick Examples pages ... [here](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/morphology/#dilate).

[image]

Not sure what is going on with the gradations in transparency, so I have zapped them with an extra `-threshold` on the alpha channel:

```
convert shapes.png -threshold 100% -channel A -morphology dilate octagon:25 -threshold 99% result.png
```

[image]

I'll leave you to translate that into PHP - should be pretty easy.

Comment: This is a perfect solution. Somehow the PHP Imagemagick extension doesn't support morphology (though it's in the docs). Thank you for your elegant solution.

Comment: Excellent - glad it worked out for you! I am surprised that the morphology stuff isn't in the PHP version. I don't generally use PHP, but maybe @emcconville can shed some light on it...